# AudioElement resume playback stutters for a second and stops

Tags: html, google-chrome, html5-audio, dart

I'm trying to use html5 audio with Dart and Chrome, and I'm going the easy way of using AudioElement as much as possible. I want to be able to pause sound and resume it later. I have:

```
startSound() {
  audioElement.src = "foo";
  audioElement.load();
  audioElement.play();
}

pause() {
  this.time = audioElement.currentTime;
  audioElement.pause();
}

unpause() {
  audioElement.currentTime = this.time;
  audioElement.play();
}
```

These are hooked up to event handlers, so when someone clicks the 'pause' button, playback stops. When they hit the 'resume' button, though, playback resumes for only about half a second before stopping again.

How do I get audio to resume properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There appears to be a timing issue in Chrome. You need to tell Chrome to play, then pause again, then play again, with a short delay between each.

A working version of the `unpause` method is:

```
unpause() {
  var fn = () {
    audioElement.currentTime = this.time;
    audioElement.play();
  };
  fn();
  window.setTimeout(() => audioElement.pause(), 25);
  window.setTimeout(fn, 50);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with Chrome. It stuttered before playing when I "resumed" the audio element, and I didn't have the same problem in Safari. It turned out, however, that Chrome was somehow not happy with my mp3 format. Adding an ogg version of the file to the sources in my  tag solved the problem.